# How to add all the list of string in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below code How to add all the list of items.

`final String item = String.valueOf ((operatorlist.get (position)));`

For the above line if I am trying print the item in log I am getting one.How to change it to list of items.

can any one help me

Response:

```
[{"email":"awdw@dv.vdv","id":"20","mobileNumber":"undefined","username":"akash4345678"},{"email":"1231312@gmail.com","id":"16","mobileNumber":"123456677896","username":"31413241"}]
```

Adapter.java:

```
public class SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {


private Context mContext;
private ArrayList operatorlist;
ArrayList arrayList;
Dialog myDialog;
String building_name;


public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList <List<GetOperatorList>> String) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.operatorlist = String;
}

@Override
public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_operator_item, parent, false);
    myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    int rowPos  = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition ();


    final String item = String.valueOf (operatorlist.get (position));
    try{
        JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(item);
        ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<jsonarr.length ();i++){
            JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
            String username = String.valueOf (jsonobj.get ("username"));
            arrayList.add (username);
            Log.d("yogesh","username = "+username);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("yogesh","Eception"+e);
    }
```

Comment: iterate through `operatorlist` and add all it's items to the string

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko give me some example

Comment: you don't know how to iterate through list, or how to add something to the string?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko please check it out is it true

Answer (score 1):

Please use **JSONArray and JSONObject** to solve the issue

as I use your string that you gave above in string XML file and use in below code and its working at my side

[{"email":"awdw@dv.vdv","id":"20","mobileNumber":"undefined","username":"akash4345678"},{"email":"1231312@gmail.com","id":"16","mobileNumber":"123456677896","username":"31413241"}]

```
    public class SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {


    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList operatorlist;
    ArrayList arrayList;
    Dialog myDialog;
    String building_name;


    public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList <List<GetOperatorList>> String) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.operatorlist = String;
    }

    public class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView mtxtName,mtxtMsg,mtxtDate;
        private SimpleViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mtxtName = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {}
        final protected Context getContext() {
            return itemView.getContext();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_operator_item, parent, false);
        myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        int rowPos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();


        final String item = String.valueOf(operatorlist.get(position));
        viewHolder.mtxtName.setText(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return operatorlist.size();
    }
}
```

recycleview_operator_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="name" android:id="@+id/name" android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

please check my log

D/yogesh: username = akash4345678
D/yogesh: username = 31413241

Comment: Getting this error Value awdw@dv.vdv of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: operatorlist I am getting size 1

Comment: can you give me a string of **final String item**

Comment: V/TAG: awdw@dv.vdv
V/TAG: akash4345678
V/TAG: undefined

Comment: please check I did some changes

Comment: getting this error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: Value awdw@dv.vdv at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: What is the value of **operatorlist**

Comment: opertaorlist contains <List<GetOperatorList>>

Comment: item:[awdw@dv.vdv, akash4345678, undefined, 1231312@gmail.com, 31413241, 123456677896, narendra@gmail.com, narendra, 99009909090]

Comment: Please check I add xml file for a list of RecyclerView Adapter.

Comment: you can also upload project on git then i will correct it

Comment: It is not setting the usernames it is setting all the values

Comment: can we discuss in chat

Comment: skype ID : yogeshbangar

Answer (score 0):

You can use gson to store class objects in string.

Add the GSON dependency in your Gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

And in your class:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(operatorlist.get (position));
Log.v("TAG", json);
```

Above code can be used to Log one object of the list. if you want all of them you can simply use a loop to iterate through them.